# How to set Push/pull columns for Only smaller screen sizes in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout on a page(with Bootstrap 3.2.0):

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12">3</div>
```

SO, it is working perfect in small screen(according to below).

```
 -----------------------
|           1           |
 ------------------------
|     3     |     2     |
 ------- ------- -------
```

But, Here, I have use `col-sm-pull-*` and `col-sm-push-*` for only small screen. though, Push/pull columns is call in Medium screen and Large screen.

if, I will use col-sm-push/pull-* & col-xs-push/pull-* So, why it is call(run) in large & medium screen?

**Medium screen and Large screen:**

```
I want to this                  I get this
 ------- --------- -----         ------- ----- ---------
|   1   |    2    |  3  |       |   1   |  3  |    2    |
 ------- --------- -----         ------- ----- ----------
```

So, How to set Push/pull columns only smaller screen?

What is wrong Here? 
How can i fix it?

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `*-push-0` and `*-pull-0` to tell Bootstrap not to use push/pull on `md` and `lg`. Also I removed the `lg` since `md` alone will work in your case.
1-2-3 on large, 1-3-2 on mobile.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12">2</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12">3</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/PPTzE3ONur

Answer (score 0):

Use push and pull for `col-xs` rather than `col-sm` i.e `col-xs-push/pull-...`

**Replace your code with this :**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-push-6 col-xs-12">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-pull-6 col-xs-12">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. but, same issue there. Here, I have confuse. if, I will use `col-xs-push/pull-*` & `col-sm-push/pull-*` So, why it is call(run) in large & medium screen?

Comment: I have improve question. So may be, you can perfect understand our issue. Thanks..