# Bootstrap Reordering col on xs width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to reorder the element in `xs size`, using `push` and `pull` feature in bootstrap. It seems to be not working for me. Please help out.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12  col-xs-pull-12">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result on all other resolution: WORKING**

```
------------
| A  | B   |
------------
```

**Expected Result in mobile devices: NOT WORKING**

```
-------
|  B  |
-------
|  A  |
-------
```

But actually its coming with scrollbar and all. I am new to bootstrap framework, let me know where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Refer these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733039/how-to-set-push-pull-columns-for-only-smaller-screen-sizes-in-bootstrap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933664/bootstrap-3-push-pull-columns-only-on-smaller-screen-sizes

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai : I have looked into that, but when its coming to 2 column scenario with col-xs size its not working.

Comment: Remember when using Bootstrap, always think mobile first. So make it work at xs first, then scale up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot use Column Reordering with a 12 Column span. It looks like what you want to do can be done with `col-sm-*` though.

See working Snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7">
      <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when col class is like this : `col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12` and `col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12` , its not working. I have problem xs screen sizes.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you cannot use Column Reordering with `col-*-12`, it won't work. And the above example gives the same result; your columns reorder @ under 768px.

Comment: Exactly, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your order as per `xs` screen then use `push` and `pull` to achieve it in other size screen.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12">A</div>
 </div>
```